# creating predefined regions in apple's MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I am new to iOS programming (obj c) and would like to create a feature for my app.  I have divided (in photoshop) the world's coastlines into 204 separate regions.  I would like to set up these regions in Apple's MapKit so that when a user is in any of these regions, my app will know which region they are in.

I realize this is a longer exercise, but I am only hoping that someone can point me in the right direction with either some basic code or what to search for.

To be clear, for now, just want to be able to draw (or define) the regions in MapKit

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial
You'll find an example on how to store your regions in the app and how to show them on the map.

Comment: Thank you.  Don't know how i missed this, but this will work great.